# Update gradle version if necessary on autodeployment

Tags: gradle

I updated gradle locally by changing the version in my `build.gradle` file here:

```
wrapper {
    gradleVersion = '5.6.1'
}
```

Next I was not able to build directly due to errors, but my IDE noticed that the version of gradle has changed and offered to install it through a popup. After that everything worked.

When I pushed my changes to my autodeployment tool it currently builds the project by executing:

```
call gradlew clean war
```

But I'm getting the same errors and this time there's no smart IDE to come to the rescue :D Therefore my question:
**How can I make sure my gradle always updates to the version that is defined in build.gradle before trying to build?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of Gradle that is used by the wrapper script is the one defined in the file `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`.

When you want to update Gradle, you could go manually changing that file, but this won't update the actual wrapper script and jar file. So it is a better practice to run `./gradlew wrapper`, which will update `gradle-wrapper.properties` and, if needed, the other support files as well.

To tell the wrapper task which version you want to use upgrade to, you can either use a command line parameter, or do what you are doing and keep the version in the `build.gradle` file (this is always what I do as well).

I usually run the wrapper task twice: first to update the version and second to both download the new version and then regenerate the scripts from this new version.

Remember to commit *all* files changed by the wrapper task, which could be `gradlew`, `gradlew.bat` and the two files in the `gradle/wrapper` folder.

Comment: yeah I realized my problem was fixed after commiting the other files - thx